# Извлечение tar архив в папку с симлинком

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tar

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы при извлечении в папку с симлинком аналогичное название папки не заменло симлинк, а пропускало если таковой имеется?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно запускать tar с опцией `--skip-old-files`. Так tar не будет перезаписывать старые файлы и не будет при этом завершаться с ошибкой, такие файлы обнаружив. Более подробно о различных вариантах действий при конфликте с уже существующими файлами написано [тут](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Dealing-with-Old-Files.html).

**Обновление**: написал простой скрипт с требуемым в вашем комментарии поведением:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import os.path
import tarfile

def to_skip(name, dirs_to_skip):
    # Пропускаем, если существует символьная ссылка с именем файла из архива.
    if os.path.islink(name):
        dirs_to_skip.append(name + '/')
        return True

    # Пропускаем, если файл находится в ранее пропущенной директории.
    for dir_to_skip in dirs_to_skip:
        if name.startswith(dir_to_skip):
            return True

    # Иначе не пропускем.
    return False

def filter_symlinks(members):
    dirs_to_skip = []

    for tarinfo in members:
        if to_skip(tarinfo.name, dirs_to_skip):
            print('пропускаем {}'.format(tarinfo.name))
        else:
            yield tarinfo

tar = tarfile.open(sys.argv[1])
tar.extractall(members=filter_symlinks(tar))
tar.close()
```

Запускать так:

```
$ ./untar.py file.tar
```

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ. Скажите а если допусим нужно извлекать так - если есть симлинк то папки с таким нахванием не извлекать, если нет симлинков тогда извлекать.

Comment: Увы, такое поведение весьма специфично, поэтому вряд ли предусмотрено. Проще всего написать соответствующий скрипт на каком-нибудь Python (библиотека `tarfile` идет в стандартной комплектации).

Comment: Написал простенький скрипт на Python, вроде должен делать то, что вам нужно.

Answer (score 0):

`man tar`
`--overwrite`
`--overwrite-dir`
`-k, --keep-old-files`
http://white55.ru/tar.html
поэксперементируйте, отпишитесь

Comment: С этими опциями происходит перезапись.

Comment: ну я просто предлагал поэксперементировать, например --overwrite=false